# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584 issue

Tags: npm, node-modules

I got a problem when I input any npm cmd, it says

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584

Operating System: Windows 10 64bit

What shall I do to solve this issue?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\FED\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: btw, I have already deleted my node_modules file and package_lock.json.

Comment: Need more details, what command are you running for example? How did you install node/npm? Have you closed and reopened your shell? If you just installed node or updated it have you tried a reboot? I would also suggest giving yarn a shot. In the past yarn has performed significantly better however npm has been closing the gap.

Answer (score 2):

For many people on Mac (not sure about Windows/Linux), the solution is:

Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then run `$ npm install` again.

You can also try updating your version of node.

Check version with `$ node -v`,
install with `$ sudo n stable`

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar error but it was because I hadn't had my node_modules(the ones you deleted ) file open in the file I was working on, even though I had run npm Install.

my Error was 
Cannot find module _resolveFilename

Answer (score 1):

If you build and deploy another place at a later time for example in an docker image, it may help to bundle the dependencies that the loader cannot find in package.json. Then the packaged are bundled and the loader can find them.

> "bundledDependencies": [   "express",   "express-http-proxy", ],
>   "dependencies": { ...}

Answer (score -2):

Before starting any project you have to write this command npm init --yes